# pip install pandas-datareader issue

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-datareader

I am trying to install pd datareader but keep getting an error. I installed latest version of pip. It looks like it is something to do with bdist_wheel, I have installed wheel on the of chance but still the same issue. The errors returned when installed below.

thanks

Collecting pandas-datareader
Using cached pandas_datareader-0.10.0-py3-none-any.whl (109 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.19.0 in /opt/homebrew/Cellar/jupyterlab/3.2.4/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from pandas-datareader) (2.26.0)
Collecting lxml
Using cached lxml-4.8.0.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=0.23 in /opt/homebrew/Cellar/jupyterlab/3.2.4/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from pandas-datareader) (1.3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7.3 in /opt/homebrew/Cellar/jupyterlab/3.2.4/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from pandas>=0.23->pandas-datareader) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.20.0 in /opt/homebrew/Cellar/jupyterlab/3.2.4/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from pandas>=0.23->pandas-datareader) (1.21.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.3 in /opt/homebrew/Cellar/jupyterlab/3.2.4/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from pandas>=0.23->pandas-datareader) (2021.3)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in /opt/homebrew/Cellar/jupyterlab/3.2.4/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from requests>=2.19.0->pandas-datareader) (1.26.7)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /opt/homebrew/Cellar/jupyterlab/3.2.4/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from requests>=2.19.0->pandas-datareader) (2021.10.8)
Requirement already satisfied: charset_normalizer~=2.0.0 in /opt/homebrew/Cellar/jupyterlab/3.2.4/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from requests>=2.19.0->pandas-datareader) (2.0.7)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in /opt/homebrew/Cellar/jupyterlab/3.2.4/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from requests>=2.19.0->pandas-datareader) (3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /opt/homebrew/Cellar/six/1.16.0_2/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7.3->pandas>=0.23->pandas-datareader) (1.16.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: lxml
Building wheel for lxml (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [91 lines of output]
Building lxml version 4.8.0.
Building without Cython.
Building against libxml2 2.9.4 and libxslt 1.1.29
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9
creating build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml
copying src/lxml/_elementpath.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml
copying src/lxml/sax.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml
copying src/lxml/pyclasslookup.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml
copying src/lxml/**init**.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml
copying src/lxml/builder.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml
copying src/lxml/doctestcompare.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml
copying src/lxml/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml
copying src/lxml/cssselect.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml
copying src/lxml/ElementInclude.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml
creating build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/includes
copying src/lxml/includes/**init**.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/includes
creating build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/html
copying src/lxml/html/soupparser.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/html
copying src/lxml/html/defs.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/html
copying src/lxml/html/_setmixin.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/html
copying src/lxml/html/clean.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/html
copying src/lxml/html/_diffcommand.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/html
copying src/lxml/html/html5parser.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/html
copying src/lxml/html/**init**.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/html
copying src/lxml/html/formfill.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/html
copying src/lxml/html/builder.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/html
copying src/lxml/html/ElementSoup.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/html
copying src/lxml/html/_html5builder.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/html
copying src/lxml/html/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/html
copying src/lxml/html/diff.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/html
creating build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron
copying src/lxml/isoschematron/**init**.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron
copying src/lxml/etree.h -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml
copying src/lxml/etree_api.h -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml
copying src/lxml/lxml.etree.h -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml
copying src/lxml/lxml.etree_api.h -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml
copying src/lxml/includes/xmlerror.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/includes
copying src/lxml/includes/c14n.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/includes
copying src/lxml/includes/xmlschema.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/includes
copying src/lxml/includes/**init**.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/includes
copying src/lxml/includes/schematron.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/includes
copying src/lxml/includes/tree.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/includes
copying src/lxml/includes/uri.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/includes
copying src/lxml/includes/etreepublic.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/includes
copying src/lxml/includes/xpath.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/includes
copying src/lxml/includes/htmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/includes
copying src/lxml/includes/xslt.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/includes
copying src/lxml/includes/config.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/includes
copying src/lxml/includes/xmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/includes
copying src/lxml/includes/xinclude.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/includes
copying src/lxml/includes/dtdvalid.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/includes
copying src/lxml/includes/relaxng.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/includes
copying src/lxml/includes/lxml-version.h -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/includes
copying src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/includes
creating build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources
creating build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng
copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng/iso-schematron.rng -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng
creating build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
creating build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/readme.txt -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
running build_ext
building 'lxml.etree' extension
creating build/temp.macosx-11-arm64-3.9
creating build/temp.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/src
creating build/temp.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/src/lxml
clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -DCYTHON_CLINE_IN_TRACEBACK=0 -I/usr/include -Isrc -Isrc/lxml/includes -I/opt/homebrew/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/sqlite/include -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/jupyterlab/3.2.4/libexec/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -c src/lxml/etree.c -o build/temp.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/src/lxml/etree.o -w -flat_namespace
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
Compile failed: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
creating var
creating var/folders
creating var/folders/vx
creating var/folders/vx/l4bxmh9d7wg66w0vvk_hsndw0000gn
creating var/folders/vx/l4bxmh9d7wg66w0vvk_hsndw0000gn/T
cc -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/libxml2 -c /var/folders/vx/l4bxmh9d7wg66w0vvk_hsndw0000gn/T/xmlXPathInitk5zjr2rs.c -o var/folders/vx/l4bxmh9d7wg66w0vvk_hsndw0000gn/T/xmlXPathInitk5zjr2rs.o
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
*********************************************************************************
Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
Perhaps try: xcode-select --install
*********************************************************************************
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for lxml
Running setup.py clean for lxml
Failed to build lxml
Installing collected packages: lxml, pandas-datareader
Running setup.py install for lxml ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Running setup.py install for lxml did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [88 lines of output]
Building lxml version 4.8.0.
Building without Cython.
Building against libxml2 2.9.4 and libxslt 1.1.29
running install
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/jupyterlab/3.2.4/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
warnings.warn(
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9
creating build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml
copying src/lxml/_elementpath.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml
copying src/lxml/sax.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml
copying src/lxml/pyclasslookup.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml
copying src/lxml/**init**.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml
copying src/lxml/builder.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml
copying src/lxml/doctestcompare.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml
copying src/lxml/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml
copying src/lxml/cssselect.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml
copying src/lxml/ElementInclude.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml
creating build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/includes
copying src/lxml/includes/**init**.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/includes
creating build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/html
copying src/lxml/html/soupparser.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/html
copying src/lxml/html/defs.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/html
copying src/lxml/html/_setmixin.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/html
copying src/lxml/html/clean.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/html
copying src/lxml/html/_diffcommand.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/html
copying src/lxml/html/html5parser.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/html
copying src/lxml/html/**init**.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/html
copying src/lxml/html/formfill.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/html
copying src/lxml/html/builder.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/html
copying src/lxml/html/ElementSoup.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/html
copying src/lxml/html/_html5builder.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/html
copying src/lxml/html/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/html
copying src/lxml/html/diff.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/html
creating build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron
copying src/lxml/isoschematron/**init**.py -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron
copying src/lxml/etree.h -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml
copying src/lxml/etree_api.h -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml
copying src/lxml/lxml.etree.h -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml
copying src/lxml/lxml.etree_api.h -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml
copying src/lxml/includes/xmlerror.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/includes
copying src/lxml/includes/c14n.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/includes
copying src/lxml/includes/xmlschema.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/includes
copying src/lxml/includes/**init**.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/includes
copying src/lxml/includes/schematron.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/includes
copying src/lxml/includes/tree.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/includes
copying src/lxml/includes/uri.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/includes
copying src/lxml/includes/etreepublic.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/includes
copying src/lxml/includes/xpath.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/includes
copying src/lxml/includes/htmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/includes
copying src/lxml/includes/xslt.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/includes
copying src/lxml/includes/config.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/includes
copying src/lxml/includes/xmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/includes
copying src/lxml/includes/xinclude.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/includes
copying src/lxml/includes/dtdvalid.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/includes
copying src/lxml/includes/relaxng.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/includes
copying src/lxml/includes/lxml-version.h -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/includes
copying src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/includes
creating build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources
creating build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng
copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng/iso-schematron.rng -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng
creating build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
creating build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/readme.txt -> build/lib.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
running build_ext
building 'lxml.etree' extension
creating build/temp.macosx-11-arm64-3.9
creating build/temp.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/src
creating build/temp.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/src/lxml
clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -DCYTHON_CLINE_IN_TRACEBACK=0 -I/usr/include -Isrc -Isrc/lxml/includes -I/opt/homebrew/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/sqlite/include -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/jupyterlab/3.2.4/libexec/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -c src/lxml/etree.c -o build/temp.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/src/lxml/etree.o -w -flat_namespace
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
Compile failed: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
cc -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/libxml2 -c /var/folders/vx/l4bxmh9d7wg66w0vvk_hsndw0000gn/T/xmlXPathInitrm8ek8az.c -o var/folders/vx/l4bxmh9d7wg66w0vvk_hsndw0000gn/T/xmlXPathInitrm8ek8az.o
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
*********************************************************************************
Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
Perhaps try: xcode-select --install
*********************************************************************************
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> lxml

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.

Comment: I experienced this same issue myself, I'm guessing it's related to the python version.

Comment: did you ever manage to fix this pls?